# Kubernetes one user per node in the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've already manage to have max one pod with containerized application per node. Now I want to create Kubernetes cluster in which each user will have access to one, personal node. As a result I want to have architecture where each user will work in isolated environment. I was thinking about some LoadBalancing with Ingress rules, but I am not sure it's a good way to achieve this.

[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdnYL.png)

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes in general is not a fit for you.

If you're trying to do "max 1 per pod node" or "a node for every user", you should not force yourself to use Kubernetes, maybe what you're looking for is just virtual machines.